# The import org.apache.http.client cannot be resolved error when I import to eclipse

Tags: android

"The import org.apache.http.util cannot be resolved" when I import the android project. I tried to look other sample answers but I still don't quiet understand.I referred to below stackoverflow link for answer also:
[The import org.apache.http.client cannot be resolved error when I update sdk to M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676049/the-import-org-apache-http-client-cannot-be-resolved-error-when-i-update-sdk-to)

Please provide the answer with screenshots if possible.Thank you so much.

Comment: Since official Eclipse support is ending in 19 days, please have a plan to move to a supported environment. In the duplicate question, "change your `compileSdkVersion` to 21" refers to Android Studio. IIRC, the equivalent in Eclipse is to right-click over your project in the Package Explorer, choose Properties > Android from the context menu, and in there set your build target to 21 or lower.

Comment: apache http library have been Deprecated long back. you better start using Volley library , asynchttpClient loopj(http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare..Sry for late reply and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @HourGlas..thz for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle

```
android {
  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Or you can use solution mentioned in this post [apache http imports not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231434/apache-http-imports-not-working)

Comment: @RAP....I added the httpclient4.0.3 jar file into my library and it's working.
Here is the link for future references.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclient403jar.htm